# I want to increment a cell reference of a formula

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I have a sheet with player names that change every 19 rows and I want to be able to quickly drag the row down and have it auto paste the formula with it adding 19 rows and pasting the data in for that row.

"Sheet 1"

```
B2 - =Sheet2!B2
B3 - =Sheet2!B21
```

and I want to drag the formula in B2 down as many times and it makes the formula essentially,

```
B29 - =Sheet2!B517
```

I've attached a sample sheet for reference.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tyJfjO5tErGSPBQaLswagHCy8mhJf7m9QM7ZJyU2I68/edit?usp=sharing

Are there any formulas I can plug in or shortcuts to use and cut down the time by not having to manually add 19?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to see what teams each player plays at?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `OFFSET` function.

For your example, you could use

```
=OFFSET(Sheet2!$B$2,(ROW()-2)*19,0)
```

This will result in the cell references you want with the caveat that the formulas won't be as transparent as bare cell references.

If you want to customize this for other uses, just know that the `ROW()` function returns the row number of the cell that holds the formula. Because your first formula is in row 2, I used `(ROW()-2)` as the factor of 19 to ensure that there is no offset on the first formula (just `Sheet2!$B$2`). For the next row (3), the formula will return `Sheet2!B2` offset by 1*19 rows. The next will be offset by 2*19 rows, etc.